# Scroll Horizontal list by scrolling vertically flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am trying to scroll horizontal list by scrolling vertically.
[I'm trying to implement this in flutter](https://codepen.io/devansh-takkar/pen/xxPyxzR)

**Structure of my scrollView**

```
CustomScrollView(
    controller: verticalScrollController,
    slivers: [
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          height: 200,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        ),
      ),
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          child: CustomScrollView(
            controller: horizontalScrollController,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            slivers: [
              SliverList.separated(
                itemCount: 50,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                ),
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                    const SizedBox(
                  width: 8,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.orange,
          height: 2000,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

I have a customScrollView which has 3 children

1. Container of height 200,
2. Horizontal list of height 300
3. Container of height 200

I have tried to solve this by NotificationListener but failed to get the desired output.

Problem is horizontal list only scrolls when the offset of vertical list is greater than 200. I have also tried using Gesture detector but failed to get the desired solution.

Comment: Without testing anything out, you will likely need an outer scroll controller for the page, and an inner scroll controller (for the horizontal part) that is updated when the outer scroll controller scrolls. You'd have to detect when the inner one is in view of the outer scroll controller, and then begin sending scroll updates to the inner one until it reaches the end, then you would resume updating the the outer one.

Comment: I am using same approach. But problem is scroll updates can only be sent it when outer view is actually scrolling.